Autocorrelation function of a Gaussian random signal
Im a beginner at signal processing and I've gotten the following question in an exercise:
"Write down the equation for a Gaussian probability density distribution and relate the different
variables to the autocorrelation function of a Gaussian random signal"
The first part of the question is seems pretty straightforward and I write the Gaussian PDF as:
$$
f_x(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma_x \sqrt{2 \pi}} \ \ \text{exp}\bigg[ - \frac{(x-m_x)^2}{2 \sigma_x ^2} \bigg]
$$
But the second part i dont know how to aproach it. How do I find the autocorrelation function $R(\tau)$ of a Gaussian random signal?
Do I find it as:
$$
R(\tau) = E[x(t)x(t-\tau)] 
$$
and then calulate the integral?
Or is the autocorrelation function known?
I could not find the formual for the autocorrelation function anywhere except using chatGPT which i dont really trust.

That feels like a non-sensical question to me unless you also constrain the signal to be "white". Are you sure the question is quoted correctly ?

What is your (or your book's)  definition of Gaussian random signal? Also, it would seem that $E[x(t)x(t-\tau)]$ should depend on both $t$ and $\tau$,and not just on $\tau$ alone.  I vote to close this question on the grounds that it is unclear what you are asking.

You're missing some necessary information to get the autocorrelation:
$$ R_{xx}(\tau) = \operatorname{E}\Big\{ x(t)x(t+\tau) \Big\} $$
You have
$$ f_{x(t)}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_x} \ \ e^{- \frac{(\alpha-\mu_x)^2}{2 \sigma_x ^2} } $$
That's not enough.  You need, additionally, this conditional probability:
$$ f_{x(t+\tau)x(t)}(\alpha,\beta) = f_{x(t+\tau)}\big(\alpha|\beta \big) \cdot  f_{x(t)}(\beta)$$
One possibility might be:
$$\begin{align}
 f_{x(t+\tau)x(t)}(\alpha,\beta) &= f_{x(t+\tau)}\big(\alpha|\beta \big) \cdot  f_{x(t)}(\beta) \\
\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \left(\sigma_x^2 - R_{xx}(\tau)\right)}} e^{-\frac12 \frac{\left(\alpha-\beta\sigma_x^{-2}R_{xx}(\tau)\right)^2}{\sigma_x^2 - R_{xx}(\tau)}} \ \cdot \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_x} e^{-\frac12 \left(\frac{\beta}{\sigma_x}\right)^2} \\
\end{align}$$
In this answer I show how you go from those dependent probabilities to the autocorrelation function.
